# Unable to connect to amazon ec2 instance over ssh

Tags: networking, ssh, internet, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am unable to connect to my amazon instance through ssh from a particular internet provider's connection. But I am able to traceroute to that ip from the same internet provider's connection.

ssh output is as given below

```
ssh -vvv -i xxxxx.pem ec2-user@50.xxx.xxx.xxx
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 1.0.0j-fips 10 May 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 50.xxx.xxx.xxx [50.xxx.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 50.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 50.xxx.xxx.xxx port 22: Connection timed out
```

traceroute output is as given below

```
 traceroute to 50.xxx.xxx.xxx (50.xxx.xxx.xxx), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.1.100 (192.168.1.100)  1.234 ms  6.164 ms  6.261 ms
 2  202.xx.xx.xxx (202.xx.xx.xxx)  181.491 ms  183.720 ms  183.653 ms
 3  202.xx.xx.xxx (202.xx.xx.xxx)  10.276 ms  10.207 ms  10.082 ms
 4  Static-37.155.93.111.tataidc.co.in (111.93.155.37)  13.148 ms  15.860 ms  15.797 ms
 5  121.241.196.101.static-bangalore.vsnl.net.in (121.241.196.101)  200.029 ms  199.980 ms  199.770 ms
 6  172.31.51.81 (172.31.51.81)  15.603 ms 172.29.251.33 (172.29.251.33)  12.545 ms  13.638 ms
 7  121.243.44.193.static-bangalore.vsnl.net.in (121.243.44.193)  10.761 ms Vlan1331.icore1.HK2-HongKong.as6453.net (116.0.67.121)  94.425 ms  94.372 ms
 8  if-6-1143.tcore1.TV2-Tokyo.as6453.net (180.87.180.37)  137.710 ms  137.960 ms  137.922 ms
 9  172.29.251.33 (172.29.251.33)  15.687 ms if-9-2.tcore2.PDI-PaloAlto.as6453.net (180.87.180.17)  255.426 ms  243.845 ms
10  if-2-2.tcore1.PDI-PaloAlto.as6453.net (66.198.127.1)  245.194 ms  234.929 ms  234.885 ms
11  66.198.127.94 (66.198.127.94)  255.009 ms  255.001 ms  248.146 ms
12  snj-edge-04.inet.qwest.net (67.14.34.86)  236.135 ms snj-edge-04.inet.qwest.net (67.14.34.82)  266.331 ms  266.410 ms
13  65.113.42.250 (65.113.42.250)  235.951 ms  245.484 ms  236.089 ms
14  205.251.229.145 (205.251.229.145)  235.667 ms 66.198.127.94 (66.198.127.94)  255.190 ms  245.145 ms
15  205.251.232.68 (205.251.232.68)  275.337 ms snj-edge-04.inet.qwest.net (67.14.34.86)  235.578 ms 205.251.229.93 (205.251.229.93)  265.743 ms
16  65.113.42.250 (65.113.42.250)  235.692 ms 205.251.229.81 (205.251.229.81)  265.600 ms 205.251.232.153 (205.251.232.153)  265.989 ms
17  205.251.232.165 (205.251.232.165)  300.965 ms 205.251.232.66 (205.251.232.66)  267.742 ms  267.656 ms
18  205.251.232.70 (205.251.232.70)  267.610 ms ec2-50-112-0-249.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com (50.112.0.249)  270.551 ms  267.099 ms
19  205.251.232.153 (205.251.232.153)  270.810 ms * 205.251.232.159 (205.251.232.159)  270.647 ms
20  * * 205.xxx.xxx.xxx (205.xxx.xxx.xxx)  300.521 ms
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  ec2-50-xxx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com (50.xxx.xxx.xxx)  269.000 ms  270.493 ms  269.900 ms
```

Any suggestions on this?

Comment: Are you sure your EC2 security group allows connections from your IP and on the correct port?

Comment: @snowdude ya ... connections are allowed from all the IP's its not reserved for any particular IP.

Comment: @snowdude the issue is solved. The problem was with the service provider end. I am not sure what they did, seems they themselves has changed my gateway to another provider which was working. Anyway thanks for that.